# PHPExcel - PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues custom worksheet

Tags: loops, phpexcel, worksheet

In my script, i have a loop which create multiple worksheet with custom name.

In each worksheet, i have the following code :

> $xAxisTickValues = array(
>
> > new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$20:$M$20', NULL, 12),
> >     );

How can i custom the 'Worksheet!$B$20:$M$20' ?

I used a variable like $name but it don't work :

> $xAxisTickValues = array(
>
> > new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $name.'!$B$20:$M$20', NULL, 12),
> >     );

How can i do to do it in my loop ?

Thank for answers.

Comment: So what's the value of $name?

Comment: Hey, the value was 'test'. I try with differents values but didn't work..
I use'd PHPExcel 1.7.9

Comment: Assuming that `test` is the name of your worksheet, PHP should concatenate that to `test!$B20:$M20`, and it should be a valid range - PHPExcel doesn't change the way the PHP concatenation operator works; but worksheet names are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
$nam="'".$sheetname."'!B$20:M$20";


$xAxisTickValues = array(

    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $str, NULL, 12),
    );
```